# Simple? Logic flaw with my function

Tags: php, logic

I have a problem, it'll probably become apparent as you read my function, but I can't figure out what to do.

The issue is, I need to use "do, while", because I need the result of "do", to test in "while". The problem is, when the while gets all 4 conditions returning false, it quits, but that leaves me with a bad code.

I need to regenerate a code until it contains no indistinguishable characters.

```
function make_code(){
    do{
        $prefix         = mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        $code           = uniqid($prefix);//good to make sure we always have a unique string to work with, even with no seed supplied.
        $sha1           = sha1($code);
        $base_convert   = base_convert($sha1, 16, 36);//expand hex with the rest of the alphabet.
        $substr         = substr($base_convert, 0, 12);//we only want the first 12 characters.
        $strtoupper     = strtoupper($substr);//for aesthetics.
        $str_split      = str_split($strtoupper, 4);//seperate into chunks.
        $voucher_code   = $str_split[0] . self::CS . $str_split[1] . self::CS . $str_split[2];//build
    }
    while(
            (stristr($voucher_code, "o") === false)
         && (stristr($voucher_code, "0") === false)
         && (stristr($voucher_code, "1") === false)
         && (stristr($voucher_code, "i") === false));


    return $voucher_code;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just present this code in a font that DOES make those characters distinguishable? That being said, simply use a regex to "simplify" your multiple string matches:

```
do {
   ...
while (preg_match('/[01lo]/i', $voucher_code));
```

Eliminating those characters from usage just makes it that much more likely you'll end up with a duplicate voucher.

Comment: Hi, Marc. These codes are going to be printed on plastic cards with scratch off panels and sold in supermarkets. The font isn't very customisable and that isn't my arena anyhoo...

Comment: Your preg_match does fix the logic issue, and it's working, but it is showing capital I characters, even though it should be case insensitive. :S

Comment: That's what the trailing `/i` is for - makes the match be case insensitive.

Comment: I know, but with your regex, the resulting codes never contain 0 or 1 or o or O but DO contain I and i. I've fiddled with the order of it, and it's perfect now. preg_match('/[0oi1]/i', $voucher_code) This works, never giving me a code with any of those characters. No idea why yours has that anomaly...

Comment: Hmm. possibly the `01` is seen as an octal 1, which'd eliminate the 0. changing it to `10` would solve that.